# Error: Failed to obtain image address when using props and creating dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props, dynamic-routing

So I am trying to dynamically render a component with its properties when I click on a button on another page with dynamic routes.
My route path is:

`<Route path="/prod/:id/:descr/:price/:image"><MakePurchase /></Route>`

then I set up a link also as follows:

`<Link to={"/prod/"+product.id+"/"+product.descr+"/"+product.price+""+product.image}>`

In the component I want to render looks like this:

```
    return(
<>
...
<img src={props.match.params.image} alt=""/>
...
<h2>{props.match.params.descr}</h2>
<h3>Price: <span >&#8358;</span>{props.match.params.price}</h3>
...
</>
)
}
```

the values for price and descr are returned perfectly but for image, there is no image displayed. I did a console.error(props) which returns values like this

```
isExact: false
params:
descr: "PS5 Dual Sense Wireless Controller"
id: "300"
image: "static"
price: "25000"
```

Please, how do I get the correct path for my image and display the image on the page?

Comment: seems there's an issue with `to` prop you're passing (missing `/`). It should be as this right ? `<Link to={"/prod/"+product.id+"/"+product.descr+"/"+product.price+"/"+product.image}>`

Comment: I tried this it's still not working

Comment: It's possible to pass data objects as the way you did for `descr` and `price`. But I'm not sure whether it's possible to send a static image file through `Link` routing navigation. Please check whether it's possible or not first.